# @2x retina fallback for .svg when using sprites

Tags: css, svg, png, retina-display

I am (of course) utilising svg sprites for various elements on my site. I am also implementing a png fallback for when svg is not available, and I'd also like to include a @2x png version for retina displays.

When I do this however, I don't seem able to contain a particular part of an image (in this case, a logo) as the `background-size` selector is only able to force the entire sprite into the logo area.

I've attached 4x images to show to show varying results.

How can I make the @2x image fill the space correctly?

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    background-image: url(images/ui-sprite.svg);
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
}

.no-svg .logo {
    background-image: url(images/ui-sprite.png); }


@media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3 / 2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .no-svg .logo {
        background-image: url(images/ui-sprite@2x.png);
    }
}
```

SVG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezjfD.png

PNG Fallback: https://i.stack.imgur.com/isVrC.png

@2x PNG Fallback (Retina): https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMqEM.png

@2x PNG Fallback (Retina) with additional CSS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXOUI.png

Comment: You'll need to use percentage values with the `background-size` and `background-position` properties, based on the location of your logo within your sprite image, to ensure the logo fills the background of the desired element.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much logic to this, i.e if the background size is set to 200% it doesn't look right. You have to use the niminal 285% to make it look right. Surely this should work with some sort of formula?

Comment: Is there really some browsers on retina devices that don't support svg? I think that svg support came before media-queries or at least at the same time. What you are trying to do seems too much effort for nothing.

Comment: You are probably right @Kaiido, I was just trying to resolve the issue as backwards compatible as possible. Cheers!

Comment: SVG has been around for a while, as @Kaiido mentioned, however using an SVG as a CSS background was something that came later. Check out caniuse to see if it has the support you need: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css